Migrate data in Azure SQL from dev to test (and prod)
I have a dev, test and a prod environment, all stored on different AzureSQL Servers and resource groups. My task is to copy all the data from dev to test (and later prod, but for now test first). I am using alembic to copy the structure, but I need some solution to copy the data.
I had my own solution with a python script, but this is a little bit prone to errors and I would prefer a standardized solution... (the script was not always working properly due to FK constraints, etc.)
Is there any automated software solution for this? I have azure-migrate in mind, but Microsoft says it is to transfer data from on premise servers and data factory pipelines need to be configured manually.
In the future it could also be that I need to frequently transfer data from prod to dev/test to update the data for development purposes.

Creating a backup of one environment and restoring it in another might work?

Can I automate the creation and deployment of the backup?

Yes, using Powershell, Azure CLI and maybe IaC tools like Terraform. This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell

You can drop the specific database for the Test environment. Then you can use PowerShell or T-SQL to create a copy of the production or DEV database.
You can use PowerShell as shown below:
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
    -ServerName $sourceserver `
    -DatabaseName "MySampleDatabase" `
    -CopyResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
    -CopyServerName $targetserver `
    -CopyDatabaseName "CopyOfMySampleDatabase"

You can use T-SQL as shown below:
CREATE DATABASE db_copy   
    AS COPY OF ozabzw7545.db_original ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S6' );

You can schedule to refresh your environments using PowerShell/T-SQL and Azure Automation account.
As a reference, here I answered a similar question
